# Two or more method call on a single event

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

```
<rich:menuItem 
    value="Download"
    action="#{controller.method1()}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{anotherclass.method1()}" />
</rich:menuItem>
```

Is there a way I can call additional methods for `onclick` event of `rich:menuItem` (or for any other rich/jsf component)?  I had the second method called okay through `a4j:support` but I need like another 2 methods separately called as our coding standard prohibits additional methods inside `controller.method1()`.

Comment: pick a duplicate: https://www.google.com/search?q=two+methods+in+single+action+jsf

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje, got it

Comment: so this question can be deleted? Any suggestion to improve the duplicate so it would be easier/better to find